# How can I parse through XML code and get required properties and values

Tags: xml, angular, bpmn, ngx-xml2json

I am using angular and I am recieving an xml response from my api call. Out of XML want name attribute of property bpmn:task.

```
<bpmn:process>
<bpmn:task Id= "Loopin809" name="Process 1"  >
<bpmn:Incoming> Sequence 1</bpmn:Incoming>
<bpmn:Outgoing> Sequence 2</bpmn:Outgoing>
</bpmn:task>
<bpmn:task Id= "Loopin8091" name="Process 2"  >
<bpmn:Incoming> Sequence 3</bpmn:Incoming>
<bpmn:Outgoing> Sequence 4</bpmn:Outgoing>
</bpmn:task>
<bpmn:task Id= "Loopin80973" name="Process 3"  >
<bpmn:Incoming> Sequence 5</bpmn:Incoming>
<bpmn:Outgoing> Sequence 6</bpmn:Outgoing>
</bpmn:task>
</brpmn:process>
```

I tried converting XML into JSON using NgxXml2Json, however, I am not able get the property "name", I am able to retrieve ID, but the name is what I am not able to retrieve. All I want is vale of name inside bpmn:task property.  (Hint name="Process 1" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
I have used ngx-xml2json npm module, and was able to parse throught my xml tree and all the properties and their attributes.
      yourXml: string;

```
  const standardParser = new DOMParser();
  const standardXml = standardParser.parseFromString(
    yourxml,
    'text/xml'
  );
  const standardObj = this.ngxXml2jsonService.xmlToJson(standardXml);
```

this solved my problem, thanks to everyone, who gave it a try.